# How to fix a window in intellij instead of pupping up

Tags: intellij-idea

How to fix the window of git changed files somewhere in intellij? In Git History when I click on "Show all affected" icon a new window pops up how to make it fix in intillij?

Answer (score 0):

Show all affected files is intended to open in a separate dialog, and it could not be docked.

As I understand, you want File history to show affected files in the same way as the Log tab. it is not possible, unfortunately. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168152

As a workaround, you could use Select in Git log action to display the commit in the Log tab, where all the details are available.

Comment: is it possible to show the file changes (like eclipse) when I select the changed file in git log?

Comment: In Git Log you select commits, the details are shown to the right. From there, you could open diff dialog. If you mean preview diff, no it is not possible. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100234 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170988 and